# Java SAX XMLReader sometimes missing characters

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I'm parsing a XML file of the form

```
<stuff>
  <date>5.9.2013</date>
  <items>
    <item>
      <a>foo</a>
      <b>bar</b>
      <c>202</c>
      <d>
        <e>baz</e>
        <e>bang</e>
      </d>
    </item>
    <item>
      <a>foo</a>
      <b>bar</b>
      <c>203</c>
      <d>
        <e>baz</e>
        <e>bang</e>
      </d>
    </item>
  </items>
</stuff>
```

There are about 30.000 of those `<item>`s.  *Sometimes* -- and I don't know when --
characters from the `<c>` tag are missing.  Resulting in the value "3" instead of
"203".  For *some* items.

This reproducibly happens for the same file.  For different permutations of the
file (items in a different order) this doesn't happen.

This only happens on one of several environments.  To make things worse I don't
have direct access to that environment, so debugging is very hard.

My implementation is aware of the fact, that the parser get's the content in
chunks.

Comment: Without seeing your java code, it is difficult to think why this could be happening. Perhaps you could post up some choice code from your custom Handler?

Comment: If you show us your code it might make it clear whether this is the issue, but for one possibility look at the answers (and specifically my answer) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771156/parsing-xml-doesnt-take-backspace-in-android/5771606#5771606).